# check the files before/without uploading with multer and node-formidable

Tags: javascript, file-upload, multer, formidable

what i want to do here is check the files before uploading them to the server , without updoaling and then deleting the files , is there any solution for this ,

```
const formidable = require('formidable');


const  storage = multer.diskStorage({
   ....
})

router.post("/users/signup", 
UserAuth.signUp, 
    multer({ 
    storage , 
    limits 
    }).fields([
    { name: 'profile', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'licence', maxCount: 1 },
]) , UserAuth.signUpSuccess);

class UserAuth {
    static async signUp(req,res,next){
        try{
            const form = new formidable({multiples: true});
            form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            if (Object.keys(files).length === 7 && Object.keys(fields).length === 8 ) {
            if(
                 files.hasOwnProperty("profile") && files["profile"].size !== 0 &&
                 files.hasOwnProperty("licence") && files["licence"].size !== 0 &&
            ){
                save the record here and then call next() for multer to finish uploading the images after they all exist

            }else{
                throw Error("some field or file is missing")
            }
            }
            });
        }catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "_check files_". What do you want to know about the files?

Comment: i want to make sure he submited all files @Teemu see now the edited qts